# Dynamic access to record column in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, composite-types

How can I address a column from a record in a plpgsql function dynamically?

In the following snippet I have access to a variable `entity.colname` that contains the column that should be checked in the IF constrol structure. I'm looking into how I can replace the `foobar` part in the snippet below with `entity.colname`. Is that possible in plpgsql?

```
IF NEW.foobar IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot be null', foobar;
END IF;
```

This is something that could but doesn't work.

```
IF NEW.entity.colname IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot be null', entity.colname;
END IF;
```

The example above is just for illustration what I'm looking to achieve, don't judge the functionality. :)

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: is this in a trigger function? In which case, why `NEW.entity.colname` rather than just `NEW.colname`?

Comment: @JackDouglas: As I understand it, the value of `entity.colname` is supposed to hold the *name* of the column. The OP needs dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's tricky, because identifiers cannot be variables in plain SQL. You need to use [dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) - which is still tricky, because variables are not visible inside `EXECUTE`.

Here is a demo how to get around this:

```
CREATE TYPE mytype AS (id int, txt text);

DO
$body$
DECLARE
    _val    mytype  := (1, NULL)::mytype;
    _name   text    := 'txt';
    _isnull boolean;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || quote_ident(_name) || ' IS NULL'
    USING _val
    INTO _isnull;

    IF _isnull THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Column "%" cannot be null', _name;
    END IF;
END;
$body$
```

Improved with with @Jack's idea in the comment.

You cannot use plpgsql built-in `FOUND` because it is not set by `EXECUTE` (except for `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` - more [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)). That's why I used `GET DIAGNOSTICS ...` initially. But finally simplified with @Jack's idea.

[`quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) makes sure the name is syntactically valid and protects against [SQLi](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLi).

Comment: Would this be a more readable using `EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || quote_ident(_name) || ' IS NULL'` into a boolean?

Comment: @JackDouglas: I think that is the most elegant way. I improved my answer with your idea.

Comment: You can also use `format()` and the `%I` placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

assuming the question is about triggers (and I'm not 100% sure I understand the question), something along these lines may be the way to go:

```
begin;
set role dba;
create role stack;
grant stack to dba;
create schema authorization stack;
set role stack;
--
create table t(id serial);
--
create function f() returns trigger language plpgsql set search_path to 'stack' as $$
declare
  s text := 'id';
  b boolean;
begin 
  execute 'select $1.'||s||' is null' using new into b;
  if b then
    raise exception '% cannot be null', s;
  end if;
  return new;
end;$$;
--
create trigger trig before insert on t for each row execute procedure f();
--
insert into t default values;
--INSERT 0 1
insert into t(id) values (null);
--ERROR:  id cannot be null
--
rollback;
```

<sub>* edited to allow for the case when the column type is unknown (thanks @Erwin!)</sub>

Comment: It indeed is a trigger function, in short i'm looking for a way to address the `NEW.name` property but "name" is stored in the `entity.colname` variable. So basically i'm trying to do `NEW.{entity.colname}` where `{entity.colname}` should be substituted by the value 'name'

Comment: SELECT INTO seems more elegant, but raises the problem that the type of the column is unknown - as the column name is a variable. You could get around this by casting the value to text and declare `n text` - as every type can be cast to `text`.

Comment: @Erwin good point, thanks. I've (hopefully) achieved the same thing another way.

Comment: @Chris the solution is exactly the same whether you are using a simple or compound type, so I've not explicitly used `entity.colname` - does that make sense to you?